# Log monitoring/metrics dashboard with images/video

Tags: grafana, kibana

I have a system that generates both textual log/metrics data, as well as images. I'm looking for some tool that would allow me to track the log data (a la Kibana or Grafana), but also let me embed the images, ideally in some way that was easily correlated with the logs based on time. That is, I'd have the normal charts derived from the log data, and if I click a point on a plot, it would show me the image from that time.

Does any system already exist that would let me do this? Free obviously preferred since it makes it easier, but this is ultimately a corporate project, so a paid tool also works.

Comment: You mentioned Kibana; have you looked at Canvas?

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/canvas.html

Comment: That's a bit unclear, specially on how you'd link images to the metrics timestamp. That's sounds like something every timeseries database allow by linking an uri to a datapoint.

Comment: @Tensibai I recognize that there are _databases_ that would be good for associating the metrics data with an image uri. My question is focused on a dashboard to display this info.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of embedding in an external page, you have some options out of the box with both Kibana (docs [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/embedding.html)) and Grafana (docs [here](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/sharing/share-panel/)).

If I understand correctly, you are trying to generate realistic clickable thumbnails - in that case, you should try Grafana first since it better supports [server-side image rendering](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/image_rendering/)